# python MongoDB Compass .command() users

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a really weird problem with the use of MongoDBCompass Community and Pymongo trying to insert new users.

First of all I entered :

> "security:   authorization: "enabled"

Into MongoDB configuration file, and than i created some different users for my local databases:

```
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

db=client['ParetoDatabase']
#db=client['admin']

db.command("createUser", "user2", pwd="password2", roles=["read"])

db.command("createUser", "user1", pwd="password1", roles=["readWrite"])
```

for which, as db i tried to use both my personal one and "admin".

So, It works as "login system" and I'm able to enter from both the users to the different databases from the MongoDBCompass Interface.

However, I have two main issues:

1) I don't know how to manage the "anonymous login". How can I prevent anyone from entering a specific database without login?

2)How is it possible that the user2, defined as a read-only role, can modify the data anyway?

Thanks in Advance!